# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with multiple Runnables scheduled at exact same time, how to?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I am wondering if the following is possible with Java's Scheduled Thread Pool Executor. I would like the STPE to schedule, with a fixed delay, multiple Runnables, each Runnable for an MyObject from the `List<MyObject>`. The following code I wrote (below) seems to do this without any problems. But I would also like ALL of these Runnables to execute at the exact same time. Is this possible, and please how can I do this? If not, is there another way I can accomplish what I need? Also, I need the Threads to execute every 1 second.

```
private List<MyObject> myObjects...


int corePoolSize = 1;
long initialDelay = 1L;//1 second
long delay = 1L;//1 second
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);

for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); i++) {

    stpe.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //DO SOMETHING

        }
    }, initialDelay, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: You will need some `cron`

Answer (score 0):

There is technically no way to have them run at *exactly* the same time, you can however have them run at almost the same time.

Beside the option you have presented already, you can have the threads at first stop at a specific barrier, then start their work once the main thread opens that barrier. Java offers a CyclicBarrier (one-time use) or a Phaser (multiple/flexible use) for this purpose.